# Select columns from a combined query in Peewee

Tags: peewee, python-3.7

I have two queries in Peewee, the first one returns a table of donations matching a minimum and maximum values and then multiplied by a factor. The other one returns all donations outside of the minimum / maximum range. After they run, I used the UNION ALL operator to get a combined set of results:

```
database.execute_sql('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;')
with database.transaction():
    # part multiplied by factor
    query1 =  (Donation
                .select(Donation.donor.alias('donor'),
                        fn.SUM((Donation.amount)*factor).alias('total'))
                .where(
                        (Donation.amount > min_donation) &
                        (Donation.amount < max_donation)
                        )
                .group_by(Donation.donor)
                )
    query2 =  (Donation
                .select(Donation.donor.alias('donor'),
                        (fn.SUM(Donation.amount)).alias('total'))
                .where(
                        #(Donation.amount <= min_donation) &
                        (Donation.amount >= max_donation)
                        )
                .group_by(Donation.donor)
                )

    query = ((query1 + query2)
                .select(
                    SQL('donor'),
                    fn.SUM(SQL('total'))
                )
                .group_by(SQL('donor'))
                .order_by(SQL('donor'))
        )
```

The way it's coded right now, it complains that I can't do select on the combined query:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_mailroom_db.py", line 350, in project
    for i in query:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1611, in __iter__
    self._ensure_execution()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1607, in _ensure_execution
    raise ValueError('Query has not been executed.')
```

Now, my question is whether there is a way to extract individual columns from the combined queries and do things like returning a SUM of grouped values, as if operating on a DB table?

Comment: Try "for i in query.execute(database):"

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code, after implementing a solution that was proposed here:

```
database.execute_sql('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;')
with database.transaction():
    # part multiplied by factor
    query1 =  (Donation
                .select(Donation.donor.alias('donor'),
                        fn.SUM((Donation.amount)*factor).alias('total'))
                .where(
                        (Donation.amount > min_donation) &
                        (Donation.amount < max_donation)
                        )
                .group_by(Donation.donor)
                )
    query2 =  (Donation
                .select(Donation.donor.alias('donor'),
                        (fn.SUM(Donation.amount)).alias('total'))
                .where(
                        (Donation.amount <= min_donation) |
                        (Donation.amount >= max_donation)
                        )
                .group_by(Donation.donor)
                )

    query = ((query1 + query2)
                .select(
                    SQL('donor'),
                    fn.SUM(SQL('total'))
                )
                .group_by(SQL('donor'))
                .order_by(SQL('donor'))
        )

    pp.pprint("="*60)
    pp.pprint("Projected Donors for factor: {}, min: {}, max: {}".format(factor,
                                                                min_donation,
                                                                max_donation)
            )
    pp.pprint('{:30} | {:30}'.format(
                            'Donor',
                            'Total'))
    pp.pprint("="*60)
    for i in query.execute(database):
        pp.pprint("{:30} | {:30}".format(str(i['donor']),
                                            str(i['SUM(total)'])
                                    )
                        )
```